# telnet login using python script

Tags: python

I am opening a website using telnet.It is asking for user name password.I want to automate it and fill the login id and password that the site asks for programatically.

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
tn = Telnet("mtrek.com")#this is for example only
tn.write("hello")#this is the username

tn.write("hello@123")#this is the password
```

But this does not seem to solve the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send a new line character (`\n`) as if you were using telnet yourself.

```py
tn.write("admin\n")
```

You should read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) for `telnetlib`.

Comment: Now a new error is coming
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip1.py", line 2, in <module>
    tn = Telnet("mtrek.com")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: ```Connection refused``` - looks like the remote host actively is refusing the connection. Are you sure a telnet server is running on the host and that it is not being blocked by a firewall? Verify first using a regular telnet client (such as the one available in Windows or PuTTY).

Comment: When i type  telnet mtrek.com 1701 on ubuntu terminal it works fine but not in program

Comment: Are you trying to telnet to port 1701? In that case, make sure you specify the port in Python: ```tn = Telnet("mtrek.com", 1701)```

Comment: import telnetlib
from telnetlib import Telnet

tn =telnetlib.Telnet("mtrek.com", 1701)

Comment: Do you receive any error this time? ```from telnetlib import Telnet / tn = Telnet("mtrek.com", 1701)``` works for me. Note that to view the output you need to use one of the read commands - check the documentation on this. As an example, ```print(tn.read_very_eager())``` should print some text.

Comment: print tn.read_until(b"Ship name:")
tn.write("admin"+"\n")
print tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")

Comment: I am using read_until but it does not take input automatically from program.It waits for me to write down ship name and password.I want to fill the default user name and password as the default provided in program

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but after going through the example given in the official docs, don't you need to read/traverse until a given string is expected?

Something like -

tn.read_until("login: ")

tn.write("hello" + "\n")   # mind the "\n" here

or may be -

tn.write("hello")

And do the same with password field.